# Second order DE in R and Θ

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For expressing the Cauchy-Riemann conditions for
f(z, z*) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) = R(r,θ) exp[iΘ(r,θ)]

in terms of R and Θ in polar coordinates r and θ, how do I find the second order differential equations satisfied by R and Θ? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Clearly $\log R,\Theta$ are harmonic functions and recall the form of Laplacian in polars.

Longer answer:

1. Prove that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac1r\frac{\partial v}{\partial\theta}$ and similar.
2. Locally $f=e^g$ (remember $f\neq 0$ for a local polar coordinates at $f(z)$) so $g=\log R+i\Theta$ is in a form which 1. above applies
   $$
   \frac{R_r}R=\frac1r\Theta_\theta,\quad
   \Theta_r=-\frac1r\frac{R_\theta}R.
   $$
3. Differentiate again the result in 2. to get a second-order DE.

Comment: Thanks! But uppercase R and THETA are themselves the functions of both lowercase r and theta. So shouldn't we get two additional cross derivatives in step-(2.) ?

Comment: @Tanay No, I have $R,\Theta$ as function of $r,\theta$ from the start.